# Query Planner has bad row estimate for second-degree joined link table and uses inefficient nested join

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, execution-plan, postgresql-performance

Note: This is a toy database example I came up with and a simplification of a real design, so please disregard from commenting about the way the database is structured.
[image]

Each Group has precisely one Community and vice-versa. One Community can have many Posts. Posta can belong to multiple communities. Assume everything is well-indexed and constrained (Including an a to b and b to a index on the link table)

When I want to query all Posts of a particular group, it's a simple query like this:

```
SELECT post.*
FROM post 
    JOIN community_post ON community_post.post_id = post.id
    JOIN community ON community.id = community_post.community_id
    JOIN group ON group.community_id = community.id
WHERE group.id = <Whatever>
```

Yes, I am aware that the join over community here is not needed, but I am not able to alter this join-chain (autogenerated ORM code), and even when removing that redundant join the issue is the same.

There's a catch: the data distribution in Community_Post is quite uneven. Most communities only have a few thousand row entries, but the a few have high five-digits and six-digits entries. These values are also very often queried and are in a quite tight loop.

When querying, the query planner starts estimating the row-counts to choose the proper join plans. But because community_id is not directly queried, but instead derived by the queried group, the query planner cannot consult the MCV and thus just estimates them based on the available data. But this row estimate is off by a huge margin for the biggest communities:
[image]
If I turn nested loops off, it instead chooses a plan that performs much better in this situation with more accurate row estimations and on a much :
[image]

If, for testing purposes, I adjust the query to use the community_id directly instead of joining the 1:1 relation like this:

```
SELECT post.*
FROM post 
    JOIN community_post ON community_post.post_id = post.id
    JOIN community ON community.id = community_post.community_id
WHERE community.id = <Whatever>
```

It performs enormously better, because the planner is able to take into account the MCV and give a smarter plan:
[image]
What I've tried:

- ANALYZE all relevant tables
- Modify different params like lookup costs etc.

What I cannot do:

- Modify the database schema (but adding indexes, constraints whatever is fair game!)
- Modify the SQL or join chain
- Enable or disable nestloops at runtime (because in prod this is only a snippet from a bigger query that does require nested loops)

By the way, if anything I wrote here is incorrect or I seem to have a misunderstanding, please point it out, as this is just the knowledge I've tried to acquire and apply and it's possible I might be wrong or missed something.

What options do I have to hint the optimizer what to do? For most groups, the generated plan is (probably) correct and efficient, but for the biggest groups it's a performance killer right now which are the most queried.

Comment: If you cannot change the query nor force `enable_nestloop = off`, there is nothing you can do. But fortunately all ORMs allow you to write your own SQL.

Comment: Assuming I was able to change the query, What would you do? Two separate queries to fetch the community first, and then use the attribute on the table directly?

Comment: I would first run the subquery that has the bad estimate, materialize the result in a temporary table, `ANALYZE` that to get correct estimates, then run the rest of the query using that subquery. This is best done with `REPEATABLE READ` isolation for consistency.